# Get facebook friends list in js using graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have created an app on Facebook. I want to refer that app to a friend so for that I want to display the list of friends. I'm getting only user info but not the friend list.

I have used the below code, please help me get the friend list.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });

function onLogin(response) {
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me?fields=first_name', function(data) {
      var welcomeBlock = document.getElementById('fb-welcome');
      welcomeBlock.innerHTML = 'Hello, ' + data.first_name + '!';
    });
  }
}

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  // Check login status on load, and if the user is
  // already logged in, go directly to the welcome message.
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    onLogin(response);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, show Login dialog first.
    FB.login(function(response) {
      onLogin(response);
    }, {scope: 'user_friends, email'});
  }
});

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function getFriends() {
    alert("in friends");
    FB.api('/me/friends', 'GET',{},
    function(response) {
         if (response.data) {
             console.log(response.data);
             $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
              console.log(friend.name +'has id:'+friend.id);
             // alert(friend.name);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even request the friends in your code. Since Graph API v2.0, you'll only receive the friends which are also using your app, and not all friends.

Use

```
FB.api('/me?fields=first_name,friends', function(data) { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. But i m stuck at a point where im getting the count of friends but not the name and details of a friend. pls help me out on how to get details of friends in facebook app. I'm using version 2.4 of graph api--may be this info help you to answer my question.

Comment: Read the second sentence of my answer again.

Answer (score -1):

## In App Friends

`FB.api("/me/friends",function(res) {
     console.log(res)
});`

## [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/friends)

---

## Inviable Friends(only in Game)

`FB.api("/me/invitable_friends",function(res){
    console.log(res)
});`

## [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.4)

Comment: `invitable_friends` can only be use for games.